# In Svelte, how to apply a class on hover without the CSS :hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

In my case, I would like to apply animations on hover but to simplify the CSS I wanted to apply a class with the animations on hover instead of writing new CSS with :hover.

Answer (score 4):

A solution I found was to combine a variable and functions on hover to dynamically apply the class

```
<script>
  let isHovered = false;
</script>

<div class:class-on-hover={isHovered} on:mouseover={() => isHovered = true} on:mouseout={() => isHovered = false}>
  Hover me!
</div>

<style>
  .class-on-hover {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: If you are using `:hover` in CSS anyway, adding the class programmatically seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Thanks but I explicitely wrote in the question "To simplify the CSS I wanted to apply a class with the animations on hover instead of writing new CSS with :hover"

Comment: You are just shifting complexity and doing something in code that is arguably meant to be done in CSS. Don't see the point.